# https:// link goes to :443 by itself

Tags: php, ssl, https

I have a few links in my page. When I open the page in `http://`, it works just fine (correctly goes to `http://www.example.com/path/to/page`. But when opened in `https://`, when I click on the link, it brings me to `www.example.com:443/path/to/page` instead, and it gives me a 400 error:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

I'm sure my link targets are fine (I use relative paths). How can I tackle this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Default port for HTTPS is 443, because of which all calls to HTTP will route to http:/XYZ:443/ by default. If you want to access the url via https, you'd need to enable/setup https in your webserver.

If you are using apache, try this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A95431_01/install/ssl.htm

Answer (score 1):

Have you got SSL certificate four your domain or localhost?

"You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port." Try to change your SSL settings.